# Why do most people fast on Rama Navami but not on Janmashtami?

Tags: scripture, krishna, rama, culture, fasting

Why do people fast on [Rama Navami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_Navami) unlike [Krishna Janmashtami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna_Janmashtami) where we celebrate with lot of sweets?

Comment: There is a custom in some regions to fast during the daytime and eat the food after offering them in the evening.

Answer (score 5):

What you say is not true.

Fasting is definitely a part of Krishna Janmashtami celebrations just like it is a part of the Rama Navami celebrations.

Some devotees fast the entire day & night whereas some fast only upto midnight which is the time to perform the Puja to Bala Krishna(Baby Krishna).

Some devotees break their fast by consuming the Prasadam of the above-mentioned Puja.

My reference here is the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu" hosted by Kamakoti.org](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=4) which in turn cites the Narada Purana:

> In **Narada Purana**, Maharshi Sanatana enumerated various
>   Vratas(religious rites) to invoke specific Deities on particular days
>   in each month through out the year for special purposes. On the
>   Pratipada day of Chaitra month Shukla Paksha, Shouri Vrata and Vidya
>   Vrata are scheduled............
>
> **Krishna Janmashtami in Shravana Krishna Paksha is a very essential day
>   for Krishna Puja when day long fasting is observed** and the ten Tulasi
>   leaf- worship is performed by reciting Krishnaya Namah, Vishnavey
>   Namah, Anantaaya namah, Govindaya Namah Garudadhwajaaya Namah,
>   Daamodaraaya namah, Hrishi keshaya namah, Pama naabhaya namah, Haraye
>   Namah, and Prahavey Namah

So, as you can see, the Scriptures actually recommend a day long fast on Janmashtami contrary to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

People just fasting on Rāma-Navamī, and not during Kṛṣṇa-Janmāṣṭami, might just be a personal opinion or limited-local observation.

In some areas or some homes/families, maybe the local-custom might prevail to not fast during the Kṛṣṇa-Janmāṣṭami

On the contrary, In fact - the scriptures prescribe mandatorily fasting on at least the five sacred days throughout the year, lest they become guilty of a Mahā-pātaka equivalent to a Brahmahattyā.

> [Chapter 34](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57347.html) - Book 9 - Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa
>
> [नानाकर्मविपाकफलवर्णनं नाम चतुस्त्रिंशोऽध्यायः](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AF/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AA)
>
> कृष्णजन्माष्टमीं रामनवमीं च सुपुण्यदाम् । शिवरात्रिं तथा चैकादशीं वारे
> रवेस्तथा ॥ ४६ ॥ 
> पञ्च पर्वाणि पुण्यानि ये न कुर्वन्ति मानवाः । लभन्ति
> ब्रह्महत्यां ते चाण्डालाधिकपापिनः ॥ ४७ ॥
>
> > <sup>Gita-press [Hindi Transaltion](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume2GitaPress/page/n507/mode/2up) 
> >
> >
> > जो मनुष्य पुण्यदायिनी कृष्णजन्माष्टमी, रामनवमी, शिवरात्रि, एकादशी और
> > रविवार-इन पाँच पुण्य पर्वोके अवसरपर व्रत नहीं करते, वे चाण्डालसे भी
> > बढ़कर पापी हैं और उन्हें ब्रह्महत्याका पाप लगता है ॥ ४६-४७ ॥</sup>
>
> > 46. & 47. **He who does not observe fasts on the Holy Śrī Kṛṣṇa Janmāṣṭami, Śrī
> >     Rāma Navamī, Śivarātri, the Ekādaśī, and Sundays - these five holy
> >     Pārvaṇas (festivals), commits Brahmahattyā; is considered more sinful
> >     than a Cāṇḍāla.**
>
> English Translation by Swami Vijñanananda

##### So the scriptures enjoin a fast, both on the Rāma-Navamī, and also during the Kṛṣṇa-Janmāṣṭami.

Comment: Was the concept of sunday , monday etc.present in that era ?? And by Sunday , is it referring to a particular sunday or every Sunday in a year??

Comment: @ShriRambhakt Obviously the gregrorian words weren't present, but their Sanskrit counterparts (वार) were present. And by Sunday (and Ekadashi) they mean all the 24 (+2) Ekadashis in a year, and also all the 52 (+1) Sundays too.